# Composer Uninstaller Freezes

Tags: windows, composer-php, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall Composer in Windows 10 and the GUI hangs with the status bar not moving.  I have let it set for several hours which makes me think it is hanging on to some dependency which does not allow it to move forward.

I installed using Composer-Setup.exe, v4.10.0.0.

Has anyone encountered this?

I've performed a whole lot of web searches.  I found some posts about removing the composer.phar and AppData, but there are registry entries that would have to be taken into account.

I reran the installer then tried uninstalling with no change in behavior.  Wondering if this is a bug with version 4.10.0.0.

Also tried a hail-mary by manually running the C:\Program Files (x86)\ComposerSetup\unins000.exe, to no avail.

Also tried a clean reboot followed by the uninstaller with no change.

Comment: I just had the same problem in Windows 10. It seems the uninstaller calls `wmic` to get info about the current user and that process hangs. Not sure if it was related or not, but it *seems* that the uninstaller "un-hanged" after I run `wmic USERACCOUNT GET` in a privileged `cmd` window. One might try to run the uninstaller as administrator.